# Windows 10: How to turn off tap sound of Non-Touch On-Screen Keyboard

Tags: windows-10, system-sounds, on-screen-keyboard

I have a non-touch screen Windows 10 PC. Sometimes, I want to use the Touch Keyboard with my mouse as it does not always have keyboard attached. However, it makes this annoying tapping sound whenever I type.

I know that with Touch screen device, I can turn off the tapping sound. But the option is not present under "Settings / Typing" when I am using on-screen keyboard without a touch screen.

Any alternative to turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. The Pop-up Keyboard *is* the Touch Keyboard. However, when there is no touch screen attached, the menu for turning off the sound is not available. Once I attached a Touch capable Monitor, the menu appeared and I can turn it off. And the sound stays off even when the Touch monitor is disconnected.

Apparently, it can also be done via Registry. So those who don't have a USB touch monitor can try the following method:

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/83375-turn-off-touch-keyboard-type-sounds-windows-10-a.html